# Unicoins ^^ - Love it - use it

Tags: discussion

[image]

I think it's a great service.

some users need to buy this specific power-up

Comment: Lols, I have 80+ coins now. KEEP MINING, KEEP MINING until tomorrow to realize it was April 1 yesterday.

Comment: @rao good thing we didn't sacrifice our precious bacon to get coins :)

Comment: I had fun with my coins. Watched mega points shrink (wink) and viewed comments in color. LOL!